# window.open() function opening more than window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a scenario where in we need to show the External Link Disclaimer on click of external link. Therefore we have unordered list of External share link. like facebook,twitter and google etc.when user click each link, lets say user clicked facebook link then External Share Link disclaimer dialog is shown then when user click ok button on Modal Dialog, facebook share screen is opened in a dialog and Disclaimer dialog is closed/hide.

Now Issue is when user click another link lets say User clicked Twitter then disclaimer is shown but when user click on OK button on disclaimer dialog, Two popup is opened i.e previously shown window and new link window. Not sure how to prevent this behavior instead of opening two window it should only open current clicked link window.

Can anybody have reason and fix for this behavior.

Here is the code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="sharelink">
        <li><a class="ExternalLink" data-toggle="modal" data-type="Facebook" data-target="#myExternalLinkModal"  href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a class="ExternalLink" data-toggle="modal" data-type="twitter"  data-target="#myExternalLinkModal"  href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
        <li><a class="ExternalLink" data-toggle="modal"  data-type="google"  data-target="#myExternalLinkModal"  href="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a class="ExternalLink" data-toggle="modal" data-type="msdn"  data-target="#myExternalLinkModal"  href="http://msdn.microsoft.com">MSDN</a></li>
    </ul>

      <div class="modal fade bodytext" id="myExternalLinkModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" style="background-color: white;">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-10">
                            <a class="modalRoundedCloseBtn" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>

                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    <div>
                        Clicking on this link means that you have choose to leave our website. While we believe that the website you have selected to visit may be of interest to you, 
                                    it is an an independent website which is not under out control. As a result, we do not endorse
                                    its content and we have no responsibility for its content or privacy practices.<br />
                        <br />
                        If you do not wish to leave this site, click Cancel. Or, click OK to continue.
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <div>
                        <a class="btn-xyz" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                        <a id="extLinkOkBtn" class="btn-xyz" href="#">OK</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(".ExternalLink").click(function () {


    var link = $(this).attr('href');
     var sharetype = $(this).attr('data-type');
    //var sharetype = $(this).attr('data-type');
    //var prevWind = Object;
    $("#extLinkOkBtn").on("click", function () {

       //var prevWindow= window.open(link, sharetype, 'height=320, width=640, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no', true);
       //prevWindow.close();
        window.open(link, sharetype, 'height=320, width=640, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no', true);
        $("#myExternalLinkModal").modal('hide');


    });

});
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey replace your `<script>` area from given code

```
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".ExternalLink").click(function () {
link = $(this).attr('href');
 sharetype = $(this).attr('data-type');
//var sharetype = $(this).attr('data-type');
//var prevWind = Object;
 });
$("#extLinkOkBtn").on("click", function () {

   //var prevWindow= window.open(link, sharetype, 'height=320, width=640, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no', true);
   //prevWindow.close();
    window.open(link, sharetype, 'height=320, width=640, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no', true);
    $("#myExternalLinkModal").modal('hide');

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Neeraj,This fixed the issue. Noticed that you have changed var link to link and var sharetype to sharetype. It would be helpful for the reader if you can explain, why we are getting two dialog when we declare the variable Link and sharetype type as var.

Comment: Hi Sameer, The actual issue is your `$("#extLinkOkBtn")` click event that is inside the `$(".ExternalLink")` click event.Hence the two click gets called during opening the window.Here i am making your variable global to access on `$("#extLinkOkBtn")` code block.